# What is the topology of an infinite cylinder?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Consider an infinitely long straw. This is a genus 1, orientable manifold.

It is not closed because it is infinitely long.

Is there a way I can describe the property that it is "partially closed" or "closed in one direction"?

I hope that this description would also apply to circles (closed) and modular arithmetic (closed).

Comment: Maybe you mean "splits as a product with a closed factor."

Comment: The torus splits as a product with a closed factor, too, though. But I like your thinking here.

Comment: What do you mean it's not closed? It's certainly not compact but if you project it on a perpandicular intersecting plane the image is a circle. So it's the reciprocal image of a closed subset by a cointinuous function (the projection)

Comment: "Not closed" is very bad terminology (unfortunately still occasionally used for historical reasons) , since closed is a relative concept used for certain subsets of a topological space. What you want to say is that your cylinder  is non compact.

Comment: The  cylinder is not compact because it is (homeomorphic to) the surface $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3\vert x^2+y^2=1\}\subset \mathbb R^3$ , which  is not bounded [since  it contains all $(1,0,N)$ for $n\in \mathbb R$ ]. Then use the  [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a smooth manifold, it's homeomorphic to $S^1 \times (-1, 1)$, with one homeomorphism being 
$$
(\theta, u) \mapsto \left(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2} u \right) \right).
$$

It's also homotopy-equivalent to $S^1$, via the deformation-retraction

$$
H(\theta, t; s) = (\theta, st)
$$
from $S^1 \times (-1, 1)$ onto the subset $S^1 \times \{0\}$.

The key points of these two observation are

1. "not closed because it's infinitely long" really isn't right -- it's not closed because it's not closed, and this can happen in many ways.
2. As for "topology" of the cylinder, there are several notions of equivalence in topology, with homeomorphism at one end, and homotopy equivalence being somewhat weaker. Since your shape is homotopy equivalent to a circle, but you regard your shape as "not closed" and the circle as "closed", you probably don't want to use the notion of homotopy equivalence -- it's too weak for your purposes.

Comment: "It's not closed because it's not closed" might be true but is not very helpful. The cylinder is not closed means *exactly* that it is not compact.  Homotopy is irrelevant and confusing : a closed disk is homotopically equivalent to an open disk , but the first is compact and the second is not.

Comment: I don't see any mention of compactness in the question. I was trying to take what the OP wrote as what the OP meant, which I grant is sometimes a mistake. OP wrote about openness, but also appeared to confound it with something having to do with infinite-ness; my homeomorphism with a sphere-cross-interval was meant to elucidate that this is not the essential nature of open-ness (and perhaps make OP question whether "open" was really the notion needed). As for homotopy equivalence, I included it because sometimes folks think topology is about various things being "the same" (a teacup and ....

Comment: ... a donut, for instance), and "sameness" has been characterized in multiple ways by topologists (Are these manifolds cobordant? Concordant? Homeomorphic? Diffeomorphic?). I wanted to help OP understand that at least one of these notions was NOT the one wanted. I suspect that OP cares about homeomorphism, but I cannot be certain.

Comment: I love John's answers and was fortunate to be one of relatively few people to take a manifolds class from him.  I think George is right about compactness being the likely technical correspondent to the OP's intuitive "not closed" description, and indeed unbounded metric implies not compact.  I still up vote this answer though, as I can't think of a better way to encapsulate "closed in one direction" than the fundamental group having a $\mathbb{Z}$ factor.

Comment: This is great, thank you for explaining it to me!

Comment: Glad to have been of service. @Callus: thanks! I had no idea former math students of mine were reading this stuff!